# Dynamically assigning asp-for variables

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a form with input boxes that I'd like to assign `asp-for` dynamically:

Form

```
@model Character
<input type="text" asp-for="@(// If Skill.Type == "Str" then use Str)" />
```

Character

```
public int Str { get; set; }
public int Dex { get; set; }

public (string Name, string Type) Skill { get; set; } = ("Uppercut", "Str")
```

Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: put it in new variable, and use it: ``@{string str = Model.Skill.Type == "Str" ? "Str" : "";}`` or in the line :``@(Model.Skill.Type == "Str" ? "Str" : "")``

Comment: @Sajid That won’t work because `asp-for` is a model expression, so it looks as the code you are writing, and not a the evaluated result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `asp-for` tag helper attribute is a `ModelExpression` which means that the tag helper will look at the *syntactical expression* to evaluate what property the input element binds to. This also means that you won’t be able to fill that property dynamically.

What you should do instead is switch the input element dynamically in your view:

```razor
@if (Model.Skill.Type == "Str")
{
    <input asp-for="Str" />
}
else if (Model.Skill.Type == "Dex")
{
    <input asp-for="Dex" />
}
```

Comment: I was trying to forgo writing 20 `<input>` tags (I have that many variables), but if that's the only way then I gotta do it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Keep your logic of deciding which field to use in your model. You should create a property InputValue and use it for asp-for.

Then use it like this

```
public int InputValue
{
    set
    {
        if (Skill.Type == "Str")
        {
            Str = value;
        }
        else
        {
            Dex = value;
        }
    }
}
```